# KillProccess wierd behaviour - Why the previous Activity in the stack is restarted?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've noticed a strange behaviour when calling

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Few things will happen after the call:

1. The application will shutdown.
2. All memory will be cleared.
3. The previous activity in the stack will start and will be moved to the foreground.

Can someone please explain the third thing? I would expect only the first and the second events to happen when using such call.

Comment: Perhaps you should simply not call `killProcess()`.

Comment: Thanks , but i was'nt asking what to do, i was aking WHY. I want to understand the logic behind this behaviour.